# Running column sum with KendoGrid and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, gridview, datagridview, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I''ll start straight with example:

[image]

As you can see the **left** column contains the running sum of **right** column.

For example:

1. 9,435 + 956 = 10,391
2. 9,435 + 956 + 147 = 10,538
3. 9,435 + 956 + 147 + 694 = 11,232
4. etc.

I'm familiar with the basics of kendo-grid, but this task is above me right now. I don't know where to start. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you wanna store that value, but if is just for visual purposes, a template for a column should be enough.

In the definition of the columns of your grid, you should define your "Running Sum" column like this:

```
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
    ...
    columns: [
        { 
            title: "Running Sum", 
            template: function (dataItem) {
                //This function is applied for each dataitem in your datasource
                var dataSource=dataItem.parent();//Get the full dataSource
                var index=dataSource.indexOf(dataItem);//Get the index of the dataItem in the dataSource
                if(index>0){
                    //Iterate to get the total
                    for(var i=0,total=0;i<=index;i++){
                        total+=dataSource[i].Price;
                    }
                    return total;
                }
                else return dataItem.Price;
            }
        },
       ...
    ],
    ...
};
```

I couldnt test it, but it should be something like this, and as much as you dont have tens of thousands of dataitems in your dataSource, your performance shouldnt be compromised with this simple function.

However, i would consider to add a new property to the model of the Grid, read just the property "runningSum"(or whatever you name it) of the previous element:

```
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
    dataSource:{
        schema:{
            model:{
                ...
                fields:{
                    ...
                    Price:{type:"number",editable:true,defaultValue:0}
                    runningSum:{type:"number",editable:false,defaultValue:0}
                    //new property,dont worry for editable false, it will still allowed 
                    //to be modified programatically and will be avoided
                    //in case of "editable":"popup"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ...
    columns: [
        { 
            title: "Running Sum", 
            template: function (dataItem) {
                //This function is applied for each dataitem in your datasource
                var dataSource=dataItem.parent();//Get the full dataSource
                var index=dataSource.indexOf(dataItem);//Get the index of the dataItem in the dataSource
                if(index>0){
                    dataItem.runningSum=dataItem.Price + dataSource[index-1].runningSum;
                }
                else{
                    dataItem.runningPrice=dataItem.price;
                }
                return dataItem.runningPrice
            }
        },
       ...
    ],
    ...
};
```

I assumed many things for this approach, like your grid directive has a k-options="mainGridOptions" in which you inside put all the configuration, but as draft, i hope it can be useful to you.